# Mixed PHP and HTML indenting

Tags: indentation, filetype-html, filetype-php

Is there a way to have mixed indenting more like Sublime Text (left) than Vim does it?

I would like the nested UL to follow the (line 10) to follow along the (main indentation).

[image]

Comment: `:set filetype=php.html`